# Control EditText Data before swiping to another fragment using a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

So, I have two fragment in the first `Fragment` I've an `EditText` . The problem is that I don't want to swipe to the next Fragment before check if the data field in the EditText is correct or no.

I'am explaining my problem in this picture below

[image]

PS: I've searched and tried to find solution by myself but it didn't work for me .

Comment: You might have to change your approach to this problem! The only way you can truly stick to this approach is if the input is optional; that way, users can move along without restrictions. Also, I would add a button for validation before swiping next

Comment: Is using TextWatcher will be a good solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your custom view pager class and handle swipe event like this.

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

private boolean enabled;

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.enabled = true;
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) return super.onTouchEvent(event);

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);

    return false;
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
```

}

you can enable or disable view pager swipe by passing boolean.

Comment: How to enable or disable view pager swipe by passing boolean? any comment will helpful

Comment: @Subin Babu you can set customViewPaget.setPagingEnabled(true/false) to enable/disable pager swipe

Answer (score 1):

this can be usefull :

```
vpPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

    // This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, 
                    "Selected page position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        // Code goes here
    }

    // Called when the scroll state changes: 
    // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        // Code goes here
    }
});
```